# Dereference with (void *) in front

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I have some doubts on dereferencing of C pointers.  Given the following code:

```
void *vptr; // declare as a void pointer type
int val = 1;
int *iptr;

// void type can hold any pointer type or reference
iptr = &val;
vptr = iptr;
printf("iptr=%p, vptr=%p\n", (void *)iptr, (void *)vptr);
```

When we do `(void *)iptr`, what are we actually printing? I thought that when dereferencing, it should print the number 1, but it actually prints an address. Why is that? And why is it necessary to add `(void *)` in front in order to print the address? Wouldn't `iptr` be enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we do (void *)iptr, what are we actually printing?

You are printing the value of `iptr` pointer in an implementation-defined way.

> I thought that when dereferencing, it should print the number 1, but it actually prints an address

You are not dereferencing anything with the `(void *)` operation, you are casting to  `void *`. To print the value of the object pointed by `iptr` you need to use the `d` conversion specifier with the argument `*iptr` (here you are dereferencing `iptr` pointer).

> And why is it necessary to add (void *) in front in order to print the address?

Because `p` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `void *`.

> Wouldn't iptr be enough?

`iptr` is a `int *` but `p` conversion specifier requires a `void *`, so without the cast it would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have the doubt of when we cast with (void *) which value are we getting?

Comment: @HommerSmith I wrote it prints the value of the pointer in an implementation-defined way because the C Standard specified it this way for the `p`specifier. This let for example the choice for a compiler to print a null pointer as `(nil)` or `0x0`. Usually it prints a hexadecimal memory address. Note that the value of `(void *) iptr` is the same as the value of `iptr` except the type is different.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `(void*)iptr`, you cast the *pointer to int* to a *pointer to void*. Dereferencing a pointer is written as `*iptr`. This will take the value `iptr` points to.

When you print `iptr` with format `%p`, you print the address, where iptr points to. It is the same as `&val`. If you want to print the value `iptr` points to, use format `%d`

```
printf("*iptr=%d\n", *iptr);
```

This will show

> *iptr=1

Answer (score 1):

To dereference a pointer in C/C++ use the `*` sign. What you're actually doing is casting `iptr` as a void pointer. Hence you see the address printed.

**Try this instead:**
`printf("iptr=%p, vptr=%p\n", *iptr, (void *)vptr);` :)

Comment: I wrote that in haste. Dereferencing a void pointer in this way will result in a compile-time error. I edited my post to correct this.